# IOS: AutoAdjustRedEye not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cifilter

[Before Applying filter Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqnlK.jpg)

[After applying Red Eye filter, get bad output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRT64.jpg)

Output Image is different every time.
Here is the code of my red eye correction filter

```
    UIImage *img = self.imageInput;
    CIImage *image = [[CIImage alloc]initWithImage:img];
    NSLog(@"after ciimage: %@", kCIImageAutoAdjustEnhance);
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"NO" forKey:kCIImageAutoAdjustEnhance];
    NSLog(@"options: %@", options);
    NSArray *adjustments = [image autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions:options];
    NSLog(@"adjustments: %@  ", adjustments);

    for (CIFilter * filter in adjustments)
    {
        [filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        image = filter.outputImage;
    }
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:image fromRect:image.extent];
    UIImage *enhancedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    self.imageViewSource.image = enhancedImage;
```

Comment: I have no experience with `CIImage` but i think in your `options` dictionary you have the keys and the values swapped. What is the console log when you print `options`?

Comment: In the middle of debugging, I copy-paste the wrong code. 
Thanks for mentioning